# Get row range where a value is matched in a column in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help in getting the row range where if a value matches in google sheet in a particular column lets say A2:A6 then pick that row range and get the count of it.

Currently for the case where in Cell A2 if "Abhishek" is present then I am using following formula manually to select Row 2:

```
=((COUNTIFS(Sheet1!1:1,">="&$A$13, Sheet1!1:1,"<="&$B$13, Sheet1!2:2,">0")))
```

Where as I am looking for a solution where I set the value something like `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A$2:A$4,A8)` for "Abhishek" then automatically select row 2 and get count from it.

The end goal is to count all the cell against date range(A13 & B13) where employee worked and value is greater than 0.

Please find the link of sheet for reference

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15eq4eTbxcPiDdYOshh6-XfrHtTuQnjsgtpb9QQonHgM/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Excel or Googlesheets? You tagged both - make a decision...

Comment: =arrayformula(SUM(N((($A$2:$A$4=A8)*($B$2:$W$4)*($B$1:$W$1>=$A$13)*($B$1:$W$1<=$B$13))>0)))

Comment: @user11222393 Your solution is working fine.
Thank You so much :)
You can post this as an answer so that I can mark it correct

Comment: One more using **countifs()** `=countifs(isbetween($1:$1,A$13,B$13),true,let(Σ,xmatch(A8,A$1:A$4),indirect(Σ&":"&Σ)),">0")` https://i.imgur.com/ZzKhZbM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B8 and dragged down:

```
=arrayformula(SUM(N(($A$2:$A$4=A8)*($B$2:$W$4)*($B$1:$W$1>=$A$13)*($B$1:$W$1<=$B$13)>0)))
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4=A8)*(B1:W1>=A13)*(B1:W1<=B13)*(B2:W4>0), B2:W4)
```

Comment: just update A8 to the cell of the name you are interested in A9 or A10

Comment: Didn't worked. It Gives NA with error message "Invalid call to non-function."

Comment: It lacks multiplication symbols between first 3 arrays. Despite of that it calculates total hours and not days with hours >0

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?